# Regex (en-US) to find all punctuation EXCEPT if part of word

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found the regex to locate all hyphenated and "apostrophied" words:

```
(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)
```

Examples: **l'Equipe** and **action-oriented**

I'm not sure how to utilize this information to get what I want after a bit of searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(?<=\b)[,.'-:"]+(?=\s|$)|"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mDhl17/1/

Here are some details

- This regex will start with `Positive Lookbehind` with a word boundary token in order to exclude any punctuation that has letters before it.
- We add the targeted punctuation mark afterward `[,.'-:"]+`. You can add to the list whatever you prefer to catch.
- We expect the punctuation marks to be followed by either a space or to be at the end of the sentence `(?=\s|$)`.
- An exception to this, is the quotation marks `" "`, we want to catch them whenever they are there, so I added the `OR |` condition at the end.

Comment: I'm not certain of any edge-cases, but this work isn't for a product - this will do just fine. Thanks!